# Facing UTF-8 issue after updating hibernate version

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, utf-8

I know this question is somehow repetitive and boring but I didn't manage to solve it and it's been 3 hours I'm stuck in it. My webapp was working like a charm with hibernate 4.2.2.Final version and I didn't have any problem but after adding hibernate search (5.0.1.Final version) I had to update hibernate version because it wasn't compatible with it. And now when I do update or insert into database, all the UTF-8 characters are saved incorrectly. Here's my config files:

pom.xml (missing dependencies are in the parent project's pom.xml)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.myproject.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>web</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>
        <commons-codec.version>1.10</commons-codec.version>
        <spring-security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
        <jpa.version>2.0.Beta-20090815</jpa.version>
        <hibernate-search.version>5.0.1.Final</hibernate-search.version>
        <hibernate-entitymanager.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate-entitymanager.version>
        <hibernate-search-infinispan.version>5.0.1.Final</hibernate-search-infinispan.version>
        <kaptcha.version>2.3</kaptcha.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet, JSP, JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--My Project Core-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}.myproject.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!--Spring MVC-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Spring Security-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--log4j-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Apache Commons-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-codec.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--KAPTCHA-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>kaptcha</groupId>
            <artifactId>kaptcha</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Hibernate-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Hibernate Search-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-search.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-entitymanager.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-infinispan</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-search-infinispan.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kaptcha.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

spring-beans.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myproject.web" />
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Model Beans Declaration -->
    <bean id="User" class="com.mycompany.myproject.core.dataaccess.model.User"/>

    <!-- Service Declaration -->
    <bean id="UserBoImpl" class="com.mycompany.myproject.core.business.bo.impl.UserBoImpl">
        <property name="userDao" ref="UserDaoImpl" />
    </bean>

    <!-- DAO Declaration -->
    <bean id="UserDaoImpl" class="com.mycompany.myproject.core.dataaccess.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!--HIBERNATE-->
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="password"></property>
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.mycompany.myproject.core.dataaccess.model.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    ...
    <!--SPRING ENCODING FILTER-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    ...
</web-app>
```

Tomcat server.xml

```
...
    <Connector URIEncoding="utf-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8084" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
...
```

I appreciate your comments.